# GWT Material Design Addin

Tags: java, gwt, material-design, add-in

I followed these steps to use the MaterialWindow addin from the gwt-material-addins-1.5.0.jar in an application.

1. Downloaded gwt-material-addins-1.5.0.jar and added to application's
   build path in Eclipse.
2. Added the line  in the
   ..gwt.xml
3. Added the line
   xmlns:ma="urn:import:gwt.material.design.addins.client" in the
   UiBinder.
4. Then started adding the line  in the UiBinder

But MaterialWindow is not visible to the UiBinder. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: have you seen any exception? add it to question along with necessary code snippet

Comment: No, there was no exception.  This happens even before I start testing. I'm using Eclipse and Eclipse shows MaterialWindow as missing type in the UiBinder.

Comment: This is no longer an issue, I have moved on to gwt-material-addins-1.5.2.jar.

Comment: I think this is an issue with the version of GWT Material Design (GMD) I tried to use GWT 2.8. When GMD version 2 is available I will revisit this issue.